# A positive bounded $L^1$ function whose logarithm explodes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

I am looking for a positive function $f \in L^1$, which satisfies $\|f\|_{\infty} < \infty$, such that $\log(f) \notin L^1$.

Intuitively, $f$ should very be close to zero so $\log(f)$ should explode.

It seems to me that one could take a piecewise constant $f$ which obtains the value $e^{-n^3}$ on an interval of size $\sim c\frac{1}{n^2}$.  (where $c$ is a multiplicative constant to make the sum of the lengths equal $1$).

This would make $\int_0^1|\log(f)|=c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n=\infty$.

Am I right?

Comment: do you want to fix your measure space, or allow all sorts e.g. bounded domain / unbounded domain / discrete domain etc? (also I guess the measure...?)

Comment: For a bounded interval, $\exp(-1/x)\in L^1([0,1])\cap C^\infty([0,1])$, for $\mathbb R$, you could use $\frac1{1+|x|^2}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks, these are very nice examples. Yes, I ment to fix the measure to be the usual Lebesgue measure. And I also wanted a function defined on a bounded interval, so your second example is great for me. (I forgot to add this requirement).

Comment: FWIW, your example is also correct :) You don't need c to be chosen nicely, because you e.g. can set $f=1$ on the remainder of $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $f : [1, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x \geq 1$ by
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2} \quad \quad ?$$

$f$ is $L^1$ and bounded, but $\ln(f)=-2\ln(x)$ is not $L^1$ at all.

Actually, any $L^1$ bounded decreasing function works. Indeed, if $f$ is $L^1$ and decreasing, then $f$ tends to $0$ in $+\infty$, so $\ln(f)$ tends to $-\infty$ in $+\infty$, so $\ln(f)$ is not $L^1$.

Comment: yeah, this is essentially my second example from the comments. Not sure what Asaf wants atm

Comment: Not sure either :) But let's answer the question as it is stated :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks, this is a nice observation about the decreasing functions.